# Methods to align divs after transforming them?

Tags: css, flexbox, css-transforms

I have a bunch of `<div>`s serving as tiles of overview windows for the users to choose from. They need to be aligned and remain certain gap in between each other.

I've tried the following methods to achieve this purpose:

1) set a `perspective` value on their common parent, and then use `transform: translateZ` to make them look smaller and send them backwards. Only selected `div` will be translated back to 0 and looks in normal size, with the rest staying transformed.

problem: can't automatically align after transforming.

2) set the `display` value of their common parent to `flex`, thus align all the divs. The selected `div` will scale to bigger size.

problem: doesn't look 3d. visually ugly and doesn't help with cognitive load.

I still prefer the 1) method, but how can I align those divs after transforming them?

```css
div#container {
  perspective: 200px;
  position: relative;
}
div.window {
  transform: translateZ(-150px);
  position: absolute;
}
div#window-1 {
  left: 10px;
}
div#window-2 {
  left: 110px;
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
  <div id="window-1" class="window">test</div>
  <div id="window-2" class="window">test2</div>
  <div id="window-3" class="window">test3</div>
  <div id="window-4" class="window">test4</div>
  <div id="window-5" class="window">test5</div>
</div>
```

Comment: share your code

Comment: Search for '3D carousel' on [codepen](https://codepen.io/search/pens?q=3D+carousel) and you will find more examples than you will ever need...

Comment: @RenevanderLende I've been there but I don't want Bootstrap or other library. This should be solvable by CSS3 and some simple JS.

Comment: Check the answer I gave. That should at least give you a starting point without all the 3D stuff.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't really need to go 3D to get some nice effect. Using flexbox layout for easy layout and positioning of child elements and a simple `transform: scale(...)` will make a lot of difference already, without any JS. Add some eye-candy and you will get something like the snippet (really need to go full page).

**UPDATE**
My motivation to go 'flexbox' anyway is the fact that you actually gave little code to start with. Also, while I personally have a speedy PC, fast GPU and a fiber-glass 200-500Mbit connection, this is not true for a lot of other people. Creating a CPU/GPU intensive webpage may eventually bite you in the tail as they tend to get sluggish, jitter or downright slow (not to mention, overly complicated).

I tend to prefer the shortest route from A to B, compact code and only the minimally required (and IE11 compatible. If it runs on IE11, it runs anywhere).

So, look at this answer as a starting point and adjust the base mechanism to meet your needs and modify the eye-candy likewise. You can always resort to JS when you need to.

**UPDATE 2**

Modified the code, now incorporates 3D layout with some 3D hover effect. Both parent and kids are Flexbox containers, so you can do anything FBL inside. The 3D layout remains.

REMARK: missed your first comment: added `transform: scale(0.5)` to child elements...

**Pro TIPS**

1) As a result of the 3D effect it may occur that the child elements get jagged (non-aliased) edges. If so, try adding a transparent outline to the child elements, like `.container>* { ... outline: 1px solid transparent ... }`. This somehow forces anti-aliassing of the edges. Beware: the regular outline will not be visible, the 'visually impaired' may not be amused...

2) Added a few buttons calling a simple one-liner JS to toggle 'custom attributes' for testing purposes.

Also added a generic, responsive page margin using 'linear equation y=mx+b'

- for points p1(320,64) p2(1920,144) (top/bottom spacing) and
- for points p1(320,8) p2(1920,320) (left/right spacing).

3) To top it off: responsive html fontsize varying from 14px to 20px, also 'y=mx+b' for points p1(320,14) p2(1280,20).

```js
var body = document.body;
function toggleBodyAttrib(a) { if (body.getAttribute(a)=='1') body.setAttribute(a,'0'); else body.setAttribute(a,'1'); }
```

```css
html,body               { box-sizing: border-box } /* size calculations up to and including border */
*::before,*::after, *   { box-sizing: inherit    } /* use parental calculation preference */

html,body               { width: 100%; max-width: 100%; margin: 0 } /* personal prefs */
body                    { min-height: 100% } /* fill screen */

/* responsive main fontsize, y=mx+b: for p1(320,14) p2(1280,20) */
html { font-size: calc(0.625vmin + 0.75rem) } /* 14px to 20px */

/*
    responsive <body> padding
    
    y=mx+b for points:
    T/B: p1(320,64) p2(1920,144) => y = 0.5x   + 48   (64px on a 320 display, 144px on 1920)
    L/R: p3(320, 8) p4(1920,320) => y = 0.195x - 54.4 ( 8px on a 320 display, 320px on 1920)
*/
[padded="1"]        { padding: calc(5vh + 48px) calc(19.5vw - 54.4px) }
[debug="1"] *       { outline: 1px dashed purple }

[debug] #buttonList *,
[debug] #buttonList { outline: none } /* exceptions to the rule above */

#buttonList         { position: fixed; top: 1rem; left: 1rem } /* keep them in place */

.container {
    /* UPDATE: 3D definitions */
    position: relative; /* create stacking context */

    transform: perspective(400px) rotateX(20deg); /* Starwars */
    perspective-origin: center center; /* center looks most straight */
    transform-style: preserve-3d; /* Kids must maintain 3D look */

    display: flex;   /* default Flexbox layout: row of columns */
    flex-wrap: wrap; /* wrap to next line when no more space   */
    justify-content: space-between; /* evenly distribute inside given space */

    width  : 50%;    /* some preferred with */
/*    padding: 1rem;   /* inner spacing (obsolete: now using <body padded="1">) */
    margin : 0 auto; /* center container horizontally */
    cursor : default;
}

/* UPDATE 3D hover preps */
.container:hover>* {
    perspective: 500px; /* higher value means a `more straight view` */
    /* try 200px and 2000px */

    transition: all 100ms ease-in-out; /* some delay prevents element jitter/flicker */
    /* too slow for IE11 (can see swap from z-index 1 to z-index 2) */
}

.container>* { /* or .container>.window, but this is more generic */
    /* UPDATE needs z positioning */
    z-index: 1;

    display: flex;           /* ditto */
    justify-content: center; /* fbl center content in window */
    align-items: center;

    min-width : 5rem;       /* preferred size, square */
    min-height: 5rem;

    margin    : -0.75rem;   /* some negative margin to compensate 50% scale */
    transform: scale(0.5);  /* scale down 50% */

    /* eye-candy */
    background-color: white;

    border: 1px solid rgba(0,0,0,.1);

    border-radius: 3px;

    box-shadow: 0px 2px 1px -1px rgba(0,0,0,.20),
                0px 1px 1px  0px rgba(0,0,0,.14),
                0px 1px 3px  0px rgba(0,0,0,.12);   /* GMC elevation 1dp */

}
.container>:hover {
    /* UPDATE added 3D transitions */
    z-index: 2;

    transform: scale(1.2) rotateX(-20deg) translateZ(50px);

    /* eye-candy */
    background-color: CornflowerBlue;

    box-shadow: 0px 3px  5px -1px rgba(0,0,0,.2),
                0px 5px  8px  0px rgba(0,0,0,.14),
                0px 1px 14px  0px rgba(0,0,0,.12);  /* GMC elevation 5dp */
}

/* back to normal size when 'click and hold' */
.container>:active { transform: scale(1) }
```

```html
<body padded="1">
<div id="buttonList">
    toggles:
    <button onclick="toggleBodyAttrib('padded')">padding</button>
    <button onclick="toggleBodyAttrib('debug')" >debug  </button>
    <!-- add your own custom debugging [attribute] toggles -->
</div>

<div class="container">
  <div>test1</div>
  <div>test2</div>
  <div>test3</div>
  <div>test4</div>
  <div>test5</div>
  <div>test6</div>
  <div>test7</div>
  <div>test8</div>
  <div>test9</div>
  <div>test10</div>
  <div>test11</div>
  <div>test12</div>
  <div>test13</div>
  <div>test14</div>
  <div>test15</div>
  <div>test16</div>
  <div>test17</div>
  <div>test18</div>
  <div>test19</div>
  <div>test20</div>
  <div>test21</div>
  <div>test22</div>
  <div>test23</div>
  <div>test24</div>
  <div>test25</div>
  <div>test26</div>
  <div>test27</div>
  <div>test28</div>
  <div>test29</div>
  <div>test30</div>
  <div>test31</div>
  <div>test32</div>
  <div>test33</div>
</div>
</body>
```

Comment: This is a nice and thorough detailed solution. But is there a way to scale down those divs (say, 50% each) and still use flexbox to align them neatly? You just want to show them a `preview` until the user clicks or hovers to choose. Now they are too big initially.

Comment: Actually I'm afraid you went around my question. I was wondering if flexbox or some similary technology can be applied to those `transformed` (in this case, `scale`) divs. Now they are neatly aligned because they are in their original form.

Comment: But I would say this is a nice and thorough solution.

Comment: @Jinghui Niu Update 2, I usually don't care much about getting the reputations, but this one looks nice enough to me. So, if you like what see, please accept the answer.

Comment: Yes I will surely accept it, but let's craft it further, why would you use `perspective()` function on the `.container` instead of directly setting the `perspective` property on it?

Comment: @Jinghui Niu not sure, copied it somewhere and left it like that. Although, splitting it might take a mircosec more CPU time, but I'm sure browser internally will be the same routines handling it. (tested the split, same result). But now: is the final result something resembling you had in mind? Also thinking about going Codepen with some extended version of this...

Comment: Correction, split version did not give same result after page reload (Ctrl-F5). Need to leave something for you to figure out, don't I? Or ask another SO question on the subject...

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/208451/discussion-between-rene-van-der-lende-and-jinghui-niu).